# How can I set only one UITableCell at the bottom of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to set only one `UITableCell` at the bottom of my `UITableView`. Something like this:

```
+----------------+
| +------------+ |
| |   cell 1   | |
| +------------+ |
| +------------+ |
| |   cell 2   | |
| +------------+ |
| +------------+ |
| |   cell 3   | |
| +------------+ |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
| +------------+ |
| | Last cell  | |
| +------------+ |
+----------------+
```

But I do not know how to achieve this.

I have looked at:

- [How to position UITableViewCell at bottom of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285687/how-to-position-uitableviewcell-at-bottom-of-screen)
- [How to position UITableViewCell to the bottom of TableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373881/how-to-position-uitableviewcell-to-the-bottom-of-tableview)
- [How to align UITableViewCell to the bottom of the UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997011/how-to-align-uitableviewcell-to-the-bottom-of-the-uitableview)

but all of them are to set all the cells at the bottom of the `UITableView` and I am not able to do it for **only one** cell.

Is it possible to set the last cell at the bottom of the `UITableView`? How can I achieve it?

**EDIT:** I have tried with two sections as comments suggested but it duplicates the space for `cell 1`, `cell 2` and `cell 3` on the second section.

I want that the second section will only have `Last cell` and not the space equals to the height of the rest of cells. After that, I want to add a specific space to the footerView of the first section.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Have you tried the footer view?

Comment: Is `LastCell` sopposed to scroll?

Comment: The last link has an interesting idea: Section 0 for cell1, cell2, cell3, Section 1 for lastCell. Then, add a empty headerView for Section 0 (of size 0,0), and and bigger one "transparent" that calculate the space to occupy between cell3 "end" and lastCell "start".

Comment: @shallowThought It should be at the bottom of the `UITableView`.  It there is so much options that the last cell is not visible it should scroll to see it but if there is no need, it should be displayed inside the screen.

Comment: @abarbier if it added as a footer view it will stick on the last cell if the content size of the tableview is less than the screen size.

Comment: @Larme So if I understand you correctly, should I create two custom cells in two different sections? But I need that the Last Cell should be with the same behaviour as cell1 and cell2.

Comment: The idea above is good, if you dont do it then you might want to just create a custom view to put exactly there if the (number of the cell * cell height) is lesser than (view height - 1 cell height)

Comment: @Error404 different section but still the same cell, why it have different behavior?

Comment: @Tj3n I mean. I want to create a menu. And the last option is to go back so I want it to be at the bottom of the space for the menu and separated of the rest of sections.

Comment: The key here is the spacer section header, not about the cell, you should have handle the cell behavior already, the section doesnt need more custom cell or anything like that

Comment: @Tj3n Yes, the functionality is working well. I only need the space between those cells.

Comment: you can add view as footer of tableview with same tablviewcell layout.

Comment: You can add empty cells with no separators. Or you could use sections and use footerView property of sections. Increase it as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var array = ["1","2","3","4"]
var dummyInserted = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.reloadData()
    if array.count < 15 {
        array.insert("", at: array.count-1)
        dummyInserted = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - UITableView DataSource
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

// MARK: - UITableView Delegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if dummyInserted == true {

        if indexPath.row == array.count-2 {

            return tableView.bounds.size.height - CGFloat(((array.count-1) * 44))
        }
    }

    return 44
}
}
```

So if you know that your table view can hold for example 15 visible rows (maybe you have to calculate that), then you can

1) if the last cell is visible, insert a dummy value into you array at the second last index

2) set the height of that dummy row to a height, that the last value is on the bottom of you table view

Maybe you have to change some code, but it should give you a good starting point of my idea

It should look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Create two section for uitableview.Put The first items in FirstSection and another in the second section.**

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"mySectionName", @"mySectionName");
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"myOtherSectionName", @"myOtherSectionName");
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }    
    return sectionName;
}
```

Comment: And where should I set the space between them? Also, I need the code to be on Swift, not Objective.

Comment: @Error404 You can use footerView for that. Increase the height of first section's footerView